# How to redirect to application, When CardView was Clicked using kotlin in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
@Composable
fun mycard(
    data: MyModel,
) {

    var value = Card(
        elevation = 14.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        modifier = Modifier

            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
            .width(350.dp)
            .height(190.dp)
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .clickable {
                val launchIntent =
                    packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube.tv")
                launchIntent?.let { startActivity(it) }
            }
```

I have added the card and the card was clickable but not redirect to specific application please solve my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Script ;

```
   apps.setOnClickListener {
                val packageName = "com.google.android.youtube.tv" 
                val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
                if (intent != null) startActivity(intent)
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The Application is not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```